# Format \section like \subsection (except for numbering)

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, vertical-spacing, section-titles

Is there an easy way to have `\section` headings be numbered in the usual way, but inherit their formatting from `\subsection`, so that section 3 below is formatted exactly like subsection 1.1, including the vertical spacing before and after:

[image]

I realise I can use the `titlesec` package to change the formatting of section headings, but I’m not sure how to reuse (or even discover for my own use) the subsection formatting provided by the current document class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\twocolumn

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\vfill\eject

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do that easily with the simplified syntax of `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\vfill\eject

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. For the sake of consistency with the original question (which was explicit about spacing), would be better if your MWE and screenshot included the `\titlespacing` settings as well. Thanks - I think I prefer this answer.

Comment: Probably I misread, and didn't notice this requirement. I'll fix that instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look for example [in this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521299/117050) we can take a look at the general structure of the sectioning macros in the standard class `article`. The default for `\subsection` is (you can get this information by using `\show\subsection` in your document, which will print this (not so nicely formatted) to the terminal and log file):

```latex
\@startsection
  {subsection}
  {2}
  {\z@}
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
```

So to get a `\section` that looks like `\subsection` we'd do:

```latex
\renewcommand\section
  {%
    \@startsection
      {section}
      {1}
      {\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
      {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
  }
```

Complete MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section
  {%
    \@startsection
      {section}
      {1}
      {\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
      {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
  }
\makeatother

\twocolumn

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\vfill\eject

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]